# different limit after reordering sum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am looking for an infinite convergent sum that still converges after reordering the sum but with a different limit. Are there any examples? Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of the [Rearrangement Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any conditionally convergent series (i.e. convergent but not absolutely convergent) will do. A classical example is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}.
$$